# Arch Linux windows managers and greeters

Tags: arch-linux, window-manager, lightdm-gtk-greeter

So I've messed my windows managers,  xinitrc and greeters when I type startx it shows dozens of errors so can someone please tell me how to list what window-managers and login-sessions/greeters I've installed (so that I can Remove and freshly install one)  thanx

Answer (score 0):

To list all your installed desktop environments, you can use the command:

```
grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*
```

It will return a list like (the desktop environment name is after `Exec=`):

```
~ ⌚ 12:52:29
$ grep "^Exec" /usr/share/xsessions/*
/usr/share/xsessions/awesome.desktop:Exec=awesome
/usr/share/xsessions/bspwm.desktop:Exec=bspwm
/usr/share/xsessions/budgie-desktop.desktop:Exec=/usr/bin/budgie-desktop
/usr/share/xsessions/enlightenment.desktop:Exec=/usr/bin/enlightenment_start
/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-xorg.desktop:Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-session
/usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop:Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-session
/usr/share/xsessions/i3-with-shmlog.desktop:Exec=i3-with-shmlog
/usr/share/xsessions/i3.desktop:Exec=i3
/usr/share/xsessions/mate.desktop:Exec=mate-session
/usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop:Exec=/usr/bin/startkde
/usr/share/xsessions/xfce.desktop:Exec=startxfce4
```